# Where can I get a specific opinion on the best tool for task X?

Tags: discussion

Before this question is closed as a duplicate by the multitudes ready to pounce with their quick-close-tool, please let me explain with an example.

SO has many people who have through thoughtful experimentation, recommendation from a peer, or blind luck discovered their preferred tool for task X.

it would be wonderful to mind-merge with the SO collective to get answers for a question like this (please do not answer the example question below):

"What tool(s) do you recommended as your Git-diff and your Git-merge tool for Windows?"

imho, there is a very strong need to get opinions.

forums.asp.net has a "Free For All" section but forums.asp.net has only about 54000 somewhat active members whereas SO claims some 5 million registered users.

For me, a brain-picking site such as stack**opinions**.com would be wonderful given that at SO opions-based questions are unwelcome.

Comment: Multiple dupe upon multiple dupe.

Comment: Was there anything new and useful?  I used my quick-close tool after the first paragraph.

Comment: 'For me, a brain-picking site such as stackopinions.com would be wonderful ', for anyone else, not so much.  SO is already overloaded and abused by homework-vamps, and you want to let in a whole new stream of idle deadbeats: those who want their product survey and market analysis work done for free?  NO!!  Go and mind-merge with Quora, or the like, and get assimilated there.

Comment: The reason SO has such a huge following is **because** it limits it to a laser focus.  Take that away, and you lose the experts with it.  You'd turn SO into a ghost town in an effort to allow these types of questions.

Comment: @MartinJames Given **A** restricted to the set of all programmers and **B** restricted to the set `{Gerry Lowry}`, then `A - B` is the set `{"for anyone else"}` which is obviously a rather humongous set.  Given that you "used [*your*] quick-close tool after the first paragraph", it's *likely* fair to ASSuME that you could not even be bothered to read the remaining paragraphs.

Comment: @fbueckert you've apparently come to the conclusion that my goal is to change SO; had you read my post carefully, that is not the case.  To be clear, my goal was either to find a website like the one mentioned below by TylerH or, if there were no such website, to hope that one would be created.

Comment: You're missing the point; the SE network is all about Questions, and Answers.  Not opinions.  Not discussions.  Specific, laser focused **problems**.  That's why the experts stick around.  Objectivity is king.

Comment: @fbueckert FWIW, it is *you* who missed the point; i already know that SO is "about Questions and Answers" ... for that reason, after searching Meta-SO and failing to find an answer, i chose to start a "discussion" in Meta-SO.

Comment: We get asked this so very, very often.  You should have found something with very little effort.  That aside, why is it the community's responsibility to direct you elsewhere?  Everyone seems to think that because we don't allow specific types of questions, we have to point them at a place that does allow them.  But the point is that experts abound here because we don't allow opinionated questions.  You won't find a site with this level of expertise that allows such requests, because experts don't stick around there.

Comment: @fbueckert read my second comment to TylerH below; i made a substantial effort yet found no question that matched the subtlety of the question that i tried to ask. Regardless, TylerH's answer *likely* suffices; perhaps there are additional websites like "*Software Recommendations". SO does not have a monopoly on experts; experts also stick around at websites like forums.asp.net as well as mailing lists and community specific groups like Vbox, GnuPG, and many more. Learning only has true value when it’s shared; many experts willingly share because they still recall they were not always experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already exists in the form of the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. From their [Tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) page:

> Software Recommendations Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people seeking specific software recommendations.
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components: a purpose (a task to accomplish, a user story) and some objective requirements (a minimum set of features). Please read our question quality guidelines before asking for a recommendation.

Comment: Even there they have to word their questions and answers as [objectively as possible](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @BSMP Yep, which is why I linked directly to their Tour page, so those unfamiliar with it can read up at the source.

Comment: Sorry, missed that!

Comment: Thank you TylerH, i'll check it out; sorry that i missed the answer that you added to the top of my question when you edited my question.

Comment: @gerryLowry That was a community vote to mark this question as a duplicate. When I answered here, I didn't yet know the question had been asked before. :-)

Comment: @TylerH ... i appreciate your help; regardless, when you edited the title, away from "*Meta Question regarding getting an opinion about where to get a specific opinion*", you introduced a not so subtle morph away from my meta question.  Please recall that the embedded *example* question was just that, i.e., an *example*.  FWIW, your editing of the title changed my *meta* question into a *non-meta* question which *may* the reason so many jumped all over my post.  FWIW, although your answer helped me, i'm not so sure that *my question* had be asked before.

Comment: @gerryLowry Most close votes had been cast by the time I edited the question, but that aside, if your *real* question is "can we have a Stack Opinions site?", the title should have reflected that. And the answer would be: Go to Area 51 and propose a new site with the exact details your specifying. If enough people are interested, it will be created.

Comment: @TylerH until your comment above, i had no idea that an [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) existed in the stack*exchange* universe.  FWIW, composing an appropriate title can be more challenging than crafting a complete answer; my question was never "can we have a Stack Opinions website?"; regardless, proposing a "Stack Opinions" website at [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) *may* be a very good idea.  Thank you again.